# Why is 'import discord' underlined

Tags: discord.py

I am currently making a simple discord bot that uses application commands to respond to the player,
for some reason, when I do 'import discord' the 'discord' is underlined showed here

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('/hello'):
        await message.channel.send('YOO THAT IS SO FIRE')
    
    if message.content.startswith('/die'):
        await message.channel.send('bro I think you shouldnt do that')

client.run('MTEwMDU4NjM2NjUzNTk5NTQ1Ng.GP_uSQ.D9Z2K0HIeWFr8KIMxcDbuHAAq40llaa6ViHG0s')
```

I am not really experienced so I didn't know what to do

Comment: What do you mean by "underlined"? What color is the line?

Comment: you underlined in red color?! in this case it means that `discord module` is not installed or not found. Make sure to install it first `pip install discord`

Answer (score 0):

Your IDE identified a problem with this line during inspection. If you're using Pycharm, hover over the underlined word and you can read the alert.
Common alerts with imports are:

- Module not installed;
- Module not listed in the project requirements;
- Module is not being used.